# Can't install eventmachine, error building gem native extension

Tags: ruby, rubygems, eventmachine

I'm trying to install [helios](http://helios.io) but I'm getting an error when it tries to compile the native extensions for eventmachine.

I'm on OS X 10.8.2, Ruby 2.0.0, Xcode 4.6.1 with updated Command Line Tools.

The error is too long so I posted it [here in gist](https://gist.github.com/marcopompei/5312559), but I guess this is the most relevant part:

```
binder.cpp: In static member function ‘static long unsigned int Bindable_t::CreateBinding()’:
binder.cpp:35: warning: suggest a space before ‘;’ or explicit braces around empty body in ‘while’ statement
make: *** [binder.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Can you compile it against other versions of Ruby?

Comment: @tadman I tried against 1.9.3 and had the same problem.

Comment: It's worth looking at the source to see what the issue might be. Can you paste the few lines around line 35 of that file?

Comment: Nothing strange [there](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/blob/v1.0.3/ext/binder.cpp#L35)…

Comment: Should probably be `while(BindingBag[++num]) { };` to make the compiler happy, but yeah. I've read that certain warnings can trip up gem compilation, interpreted as errors when they should be ignored. Maybe this is needs to be raised as an Issue on eventmachine? Which version of `gem` are you using? 2.0.3 is current.

Comment: @tadman I'm using 2.0.3. I fixed the warning and than the gem installs. Thank you! I'll write a ticket.

Comment: @MarcoPompei How you solved this problem? I am getting the same error while installing helios.